# password-reset/change-password on Symfony4 built-in security

Tags: php, symfony4

in Symfony2, I have used FOSUserBundle.

It has `login/register/password-reset/change-password`

Now in Symfony4, I am using built-in Security system and `login/register` is implemented by this document.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security.html

However, I can't find how to set `password-reset/change-password` controller.

Is there any sample or document for Symfony4 `password-reset/change-password`

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 4 does not come with controllers for password reset and change password functionality. You can continue to use FOSUserBundle which also works on Symfony4.